# Inno Setup: Install other installer and run it before continuing my install

Tags: installation, inno-setup

This is the [Files] portion of my code so far:

```
[Files]
Source: "other_installer.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "myprogram.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "data.dat"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "otherdata.dat"; DestDir: "{app}"
```

My program is dependent on another program to run. I've included the installer for this program ("other_installer.exe") in my installer. What I would like to do is launch this installer as soon as it has been copied, before continuing with "myprogram.exe" and the rest.

I've googled and found the documentation for BeforeInstall in the Inno Setup Help, but they don't have an example of running another application. I believe it should be something like this:

```
[Files]
Source: "other_installer.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "myprogram.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; BeforeInstall: // RUN OTHER_INSTALLER.EXE //
Source: "data.dat"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "otherdata.dat"; DestDir: "{app}"
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Better for the way you go might be the [`AfterInstall`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptinstall&anchor=AfterInstall) parameter. The following script will execute the `RunOtherInstaller` function right after the `OtherInstaller.exe` file entry is processed. There it tries to execute the just installed `OtherInstaller.exe` file and if that fails, it reports an error message to the user. Please note that you cannot interrupt the installation from that function, so it's not much safe to do what you want this way:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program

[Files]
Source: "OtherInstaller.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; AfterInstall: RunOtherInstaller
Source: "OtherFile.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"

[Code]
procedure RunOtherInstaller;
var
  ResultCode: Integer;
begin
  if not Exec(ExpandConstant('{app}\OtherInstaller.exe'), '', '', SW_SHOWNORMAL,
    ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode)
  then
    MsgBox('Other installer failed to run!' + #13#10 +
      SysErrorMessage(ResultCode), mbError, MB_OK);
end;
```

Comment: Would it be possible to store the error and interrupt (and potentially rollback) the installation later?

Comment: I tried it although I got the error: "the request requires elevation". How do I manage it please?

Comment: It worked like a charm. However, what to do for non-executable files? I am trying to open a `p12` ceritificate file and it throws me the error: `%1 is not a valid win32 application`.

Answer (score 15):

Another good time to run prerequisite installers is in the `PrepareToInstall` event function.  (See the example scripts provided with Inno for the basic structure, and TLama's code for the actual execution.)

The main advantage of `PrepareToInstall` is that it allows you to handle errors and reboot requests from the child installer -- using `AfterInstall` doesn't.

The main disadvantage of it is that you have to manually `ExtractTemporaryFile` anything required to run the child install, as this occurs prior to files being extracted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use AfterInstall, look for this in the Help.
When file is just copied, i'll launch the function/procedure you put as "AfterInstall:".

In this function/procedure, use Exec and launch the other installer.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry if my answer is similar to yours